# Why does sound follow the laws of reflection, I read in Feynman lectures that Q mech is the real reason for Fermat's principle but why sound follows?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, acoustics

You can also check out science asylum video on how mirrors work, he explains similar thing as written in Feynman lectures.
But I do not understand why sound should follow the same thing

Comment: Link & minute of video? Link & page in Feynman lectures?

Comment: You should explain, why you can not see reflection laws for any kind of waves. So please explain exactly what your doubts are. You can not expect helpers to find a video or a certain page of lectures just to give an answer.